# How to untar a TAR file using Apache Commons

Tags: java, file-io, tar, apache-commons, compression

I'm using the Apache Commons 1.4.1 library to compress and uncompress `".tar.gz"` files.

I'm having trouble with the last bit -- converting a `TarArchiveInputStream` into a `FileOutputStream`.

Oddly enough, it's breaking on this line:

```
FileOutputStream fout = new FileOutputStream(destPath);
```

---

`destPath` is a File with a Canonical path of: C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\My Documents\JavaWorkspace\BackupUtility\untarred\Test\subdir\testinsub.txt

Error produced:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: The system cannot find the path specified
```

Any idea what it could be? And why is it not able to find the path?

I'm attaching the whole method below (most of which is lifted from [here](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache%3aOQ1Ex8ChLpkJ%3awww.thetechallies.com/node/4%20&cd=10&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=mt)).

```
private void untar(File dest) throws IOException {
    dest.mkdir();
    TarArchiveEntry tarEntry = tarIn.getNextTarEntry();
    // tarIn is a TarArchiveInputStream
    while (tarEntry != null) {// create a file with the same name as the tarEntry
        File destPath = new File(dest.toString() + System.getProperty("file.separator") + tarEntry.getName());
        System.out.println("working: " + destPath.getCanonicalPath());
        if (tarEntry.isDirectory()) {
            destPath.mkdirs();
        } else {
            destPath.createNewFile();
            FileOutputStream fout = new FileOutputStream(destPath);
            tarIn.read(new byte[(int) tarEntry.getSize()]);
            fout.close();
        }
        tarEntry = tarIn.getNextTarEntry();
    }
    tarIn.close();
}
```

Comment: Embarrassed to ask this, but I tried using your code sample and saw it work given a particular `gzip` file I was working with.  How is it this works without any call to `fout.write(...)` given the content read on the inputStream?  In the [answer @user1894600 suggests](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14211580/320399), he has to explicitly call `write(...)` and provide the byte array that has been read into memory.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A couple of general points, why do you do voodoo with the `File` constructor, where there is a [perfectly usable constructor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#File%28java.io.File,%20java.lang.String%29) where you can define the name of the `File` you want to create and give a parent File?

Secondly I am not too sure how empty spaces are handled in paths in windows. It might be the cause of your problems. Try using the constructor I mentioned above and see if it makes a difference: `File destPath = new File(dest, tarEntry.getName());` (assuming that `File dest` is a proper file, and exists and is accessible by you.

Third, before you do anything with a `File` object you should check if it exists and if it is accessible. That will ultimately help you pinpoint the problem.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I've decided to rewrite the module and it works great. I've taken your advice about not playing with the File object, and so I'm going to mark your answer as the correct one (based on the principle)

Comment: Glad it helped, and hope it all works out fine in the end. Good luck :)

Comment: I am using same code to untar  a .tar file not the .tar.gz. And I am getting from this line 'new File(dest, tarEntry.getName())' the file content not the file name. What can I do to get the filename inside the .tar

Answer (score 18):

Your program has the java heap space error.
so I think a little change needed.
here is code...

```
public static void uncompressTarGZ(File tarFile, File dest) throws IOException {
    dest.mkdir();
    TarArchiveInputStream tarIn = null;

    tarIn = new TarArchiveInputStream(
                new GzipCompressorInputStream(
                    new BufferedInputStream(
                        new FileInputStream(
                            tarFile
                        )
                    )
                )
            );

    TarArchiveEntry tarEntry = tarIn.getNextTarEntry();
    // tarIn is a TarArchiveInputStream
    while (tarEntry != null) {// create a file with the same name as the tarEntry
        File destPath = new File(dest, tarEntry.getName());
        System.out.println("working: " + destPath.getCanonicalPath());
        if (tarEntry.isDirectory()) {
            destPath.mkdirs();
        } else {
            destPath.createNewFile();
            //byte [] btoRead = new byte[(int)tarEntry.getSize()];
            byte [] btoRead = new byte[1024];
            //FileInputStream fin 
            //  = new FileInputStream(destPath.getCanonicalPath());
            BufferedOutputStream bout = 
                new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(destPath));
            int len = 0;

            while((len = tarIn.read(btoRead)) != -1)
            {
                bout.write(btoRead,0,len);
            }

            bout.close();
            btoRead = null;

        }
        tarEntry = tarIn.getNextTarEntry();
    }
    tarIn.close();
}
```

good luck

Comment: So, the heap space error would occur because the byte array is potentially too large when it's declared as `byte [] btoRead = new byte[(int)tarEntry.getSize()];` ?

Comment: Excellent response.  However, the following `deskPath.createNewFile();` should be modified to create the parent directory `if (!destPath.getParentFile().exists()) {
                    destPath.getParentFile().mkdirs();
                }
                destPath.createNewFile();`