# Listing tar archive contents (java commons compress) returns variable number of entries, then stream closed exception. How to fix?

Tags: java, tar, apache-commons-compress

I have researched this issue for quite some time on google and stackoverflow. 
 Unfortunately, I can't seem to find any resources that seem to address this issue.  Admittedly, my search-fu isn't the best; any help, examples, or pointers to relevant resources will be very much appreciated.

The following code is my method for listing the archive contents from a *TarArchiveInputStream*:

```
public static List<String> tarListDir(InputStream incoming) 
    throws Exception {
    TarArchiveInputStream tarInput = new TarArchiveInputStream(incoming);
    TarArchiveEntry entry = null;
    List<String> ouah = new ArrayList<String>();

    try {
        while ((entry = tarInput.getNextTarEntry()) != null) {
            if (!entry.isFile()) {
                continue;
            }

            ouah.add(entry.getName());

            if (RecScan.verbose || RecScan.debugging) {
                if (entry.isFile()) {
                    System.out.print("file: \t");
                } else if (entry.isDirectory()) {
                    System.out.print("dir: \t");
                } else {
                    System.out.print("wut: \t");
                }

                System.out.println(ouah.get(ouah.size() - 1));
            }

        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        tarInput.close();
        throw new Exception("Closed w/exception: " + e.getMessage());
    }

    if (RecScan.verbose || RecScan.debugging) {
        System.out.println("Closing tarInput normally");
    }
    tarInput.close();

    return ouah;
}
```

As mentioned above, I am hoping to obtain the *List* of entries in the archive.  Unfortunately, it appears that the method is only obtaining a random amount of directory entries.  This number varies, per-archive (testing with 4 different ones), from 0 entries to 12 entries.  The exception that is being thrown is an *IOException*, *Stream Closed* to be specific.

I'm not very well versed in the Apache Commons Compress libraries (obviously), and I don't really know any hex editors well enough to dig around in the archive to see if there's something non-POSIX that it's stumbling over.  I would think that the `entry.isFile()` conditional would avoid that complication, though.

As I mentioned, any help or resources greatly appreciated!  TIA!

**EDIT**: Though the code there (in the first comment's post reference) seemed to boil down basically to the same as what I was using, I did actually cut out my code and use what was there, virtually verbatim. Still got the exact same error: `Stream Closed`. I did manage to find something that may hold a clue; I tried swapping out the `BufferedInputStream` wrapping of the original `InputStream` that I handed off. This caused the **Stream Closed** error immediately, vs. the `BufferedInputStream` closing after a bit of the archive listing. Definitely still looking for hints.

Comment: Did you check https://stackoverflow.com/a/7556307/3179169. The comments talk about the same issue as you and there might be a recommendation posted there.

Comment: I didn't see anything for a solution or a recommendation there.  :P

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14211580/3179169 Did you try doing it this way?

Comment: Though the code there seemed to boil down basically to the same as what I was using, I did actually cut out my code and use what was there, virtually verbatim.  Still got the exact same error: **Stream Closed**.

I did manage to find something that may hold a clue; I tried swapping out the `BufferedInputStream` wrapping of the original `InputStream` that I handed off.  This caused the **Stream Closed** error immediately, vs. the `BufferedInputStream` closing after a bit of the archive listing.

Definitely still looking for hints.